# if a pop up shows in the app on login I want to tap the ok if it does not appear I want the test to continue

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, xamarin.uitest

its Xamarin and using if else is causing errors.I tried below but it gave me many issues that else can't start a line and other issues. It could be there is a better way to do this but everything I have tried is an issue. Will this work for both Android and IoS I googled this and went to xamarin docs but its not answered easily.

```
        if( app.Query(x => x.Id("button2").Invoke("exists","button2")));
        { app.Tap("button2");
        } {}
        else {
            app.WaitForElement(x => x.Id("contentPanel"), timeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));
```

Comment: You mean that the code above don't work?

Comment: Correct the code above does not work but that is what I have attempted.

Comment: is there one exists method in your uitest? it is public?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try assigning the Xamarin query to a variable instead of invoking that 'exisits' method. Try the following:

```
var okButton = app.Query(x => x.Id("button2")).SingleOrDefault();

if(okButton != null)
{
    app.Tap(x => x.Id("button2"))
}
else 
{
    app.WaitForElement(x => x.Id("contentPanel"), timeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));
}
```